# How can I reduce the width of a bootstrap grid column without custom css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row in a grid with a checkbox and an input field, like so:
[image]

The checkbox only takes up one grid column, but it is still too wide. Is it possible to reduce the width of the cell without hackey custom css code?

```
<div class="row requestQuoteForm-CustomVendorRow-Container">
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <input type="checkbox" >
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="validatedInputGroupsStacked">
        <div data-bind="template: { icon:'fa-truck'} }"></div>
        <div data-bind="template: { icon:'fa-envelope'} }"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you could try wrapping `ìnput` in another `div.col-sm-6` (it should reduce input's wrapper by 50%)

Comment: Why doesn't wrapping it in a col-sm-3 reduce the width even further? Is it recommended that I wrap the additional div in a `row` class?

Comment: `col-sm-6` or `col-sm-3` define % width, `.col-sm-6{ width:50%}` and `.col-sm-3{ width:25%}` , this is relative to parent container . if you just want to move the checkbox (if that's what you want to do ) it might be better to look into .col-md-push-* and .col-md-pull-* modifier classe